# How to use WebDriver with Java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Selenium RC, TestNG, Java with Eclipse. I want to use WebDriver.

How can I use it? Which jar file will be added in eclipse as external jar file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the [selenium-java zip](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-java-2.0b3.zip&can=2&q=) and add all the Jars in the lib dir to your classpath.
This will contain the WebDriver API and all the available browser Drivers such as Firefox, HTMLUnit, Chrome, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With WebDriver + Java + TestNG + Maven + ReportNG + Sikuli you can make an automation framework which is user friendly, robust, maintainable and scalable. Tools, strategies and patterns that I used are explained in detail at http://xebee.xebia.in/2012/03/30/web-gui-automation-tools-strategies-patterns/

Answer (score 1):

Please look at my step by step guide at http://scraping.pro/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-with-java/. It explains how to build a java program that uses WebDriver using Eclipse IDE.